# Image.onload function returns zero for height and width

Tags: javascript

```
var icon1 = new Image();
var wid1;
var hei1;
icon1.onload = function () {
    wid1 = icon1.width;
    hei1 = icon1.height;
};
icon1.src = resource;
var rati = wid1 / hei1;
```

What I am trying to do is to get the width and height of the image and then calculate the ratio that will further help to maintain the aspect ratio of the image.

But when I run this code, lot of times I get the width and height of image as `0` that will result turning ratio to `NaN` and finally the image never loads because of `0` height and width. Any Help?

Comment: You are calculating `rati` **before** the `onload` callback was executed. You have to calculate it **inside** the callback, when the values are available.

Answer (score 2):

This operation runs asynchronously. The line:

```
var rati=wid1/hei1;
```

Runs regardless if the image is loaded or not. This means the `wid1` and `hei1` are `undefined` and dividing two undefined values results to `NaN`.

Make sure `wid1` and `hei1` are loaded before doing operations on them. What you can do is place the divide operation inside the `onload` handler (as well as everything else that depends on those values:

```
var icon1, wid1, hei1, rati;

//create our image object
icon1 = new Image();

icon1.onload = function () {
    wid1 = icon1.width;
    hei1 = icon1.height;
    rati = wid1 / hei1;

    //everything else that depends on these variables 
    //should be placed here as well

};

//start loadin'
icon1.src = resource;
```

Comment: I need to return the *width* and *height* of the image from the `icon1.onload()` to some other function. How can it be done? Should I use the return statement inside the `onload()` or is there some other way?

Comment: @barnes You can't technically "return" as `onload` is executed asynchronously. The closest to a returnable is a Promise, but it's still async. You execute the continuation of your code in a callback.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript loads images asynchronously, so you are trying to calculate the ratio while the image is still loading. You have to move the calculation into the callback function:

```
var icon1 = new Image();
var wid1;
var hei1;
icon1.src = resource;
icon1.onload = function () {
    wid1 = icon1.width;
    hei1 = icon1.height;
    var rati = wid1 / hei1;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem where the image.width and image.height were 0 within the onload callback.  They were set for jpg files and not set when I loaded a png.
I fixed this by using this.width and this.height in the onload callback function.  Those were not zero.
Maybe this will help someone else.  I was using chrome.

Comment: Thank you so much, I had an issue when an image is loaded but the site is not in view / not focus, onLoad would give me image.width = 0 and image.height = 0

Answer (score 0):

Race condition. You are defining `rati` before the image has loaded, so obviously it can't know the right size and does `undefined/undefined`. To fix, just put all the code that requires the image to be loaded, inside the `icon1.onload` handler.

Comment: so the rati variable should be in icon1.onload handler?